# How to configure apache to allow access to subdomain on my local ip address

Tags: apache, server, http-server, ip-address

I would like to have others inside my local network access resources on my computer at `outsideprojects.192.168.0.10`. I am running Apache and have a virtual host configured so I can access it at `outsideprojects.localhost` but can't seem to be able to access it from the outside.

I have all firewalls disabled so I don't believe that this is the issue. I would expect that I should be able to access this at `outsideprojects.127.0.0.1` but I cannot do that either.

What are the Apache configuration options to be able to accomplish this?

Comment: After posting here I realized that his is probably a better question for serverfault. I have asked it there as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/189239/how-to-configure-apache-to-allow-access-to-subdomain-on-my-local-ip-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing that with a subdomain from something like http://www.dyndns.com/ opposed to using an ip address.  I imagine that would work better with apache if you want to configure it that way.  to access this from a remote host you would have to open up your firewall and also forward the port from your router.

I'm not very familure with apache's configuration but just with the dyndns.com subdomain I access a webserver I have running on my development machine from anywhere without too much trouble.

**EDIT** : now that I notice you want this for your local *network* ...
why the subdomain? The ip address of your machine should be enough? if you want multiple sites just run it on different ports. so 192.168.0.10:80 , 192.168.0.10:81, 192.168.0.10:82.  that would be the easiest thing to do.
OR another thing you can do is use the name of the computer, which acts as a host name over a local network.  I have no idea if subdomains work with that.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I think the port suggestion will be my solution.

Comment: don't forget to upvote helpfull solutions and questions,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that from outside network. But for local network you may:
To do this only for the localhost:
open /etc/hosts, you will see 1 line:
 127.0.0.1 localhost
add another line:
127.0.0.1 outsideprojects.192.168.0.10

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf you can add this address as another host.

But be assured, this is "not possible" from outside network, because IP addresses can never contain subdomains!